# How can I parse the unit : "g/100mL" using unit-parse in Python?

Tags: python, text-parsing, units-of-measurement, pint

I'm trying to parse strings in Python, looking for scientific values and units. I want to retrieve them in order to convert them to some other units.

I'm using the library [unit-parse](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/0.20.1/advanced/defining.html) (based on [pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/0.20.1/advanced/defining.html)) but it has trouble understanding this example : `12.5g/100ml`.

I managed a workaround : replacing `g/100mL` in the string by another word (`stuff` for example in the code below) and using this word as a new unit (equivalent to `(g/l) * 10`)

My code:

```py
import logging

import pint

u = pint.UnitRegistry()
U = Unit = u.Unit
Q = Quantity = u.Quantity

from unit_parse import parser, logger, config


def display(text):
    text = text.replace(" ", "")  # Suppress spaces.
    result = parser(text)

    print(f"RESULT = {result}")
    print(f"VALUE = {result.m}")
    print(f"UNIT = {result.u}")

    print(f"to g/l = {result.to('g/L')}")
    print(f"to g/ml = {result.to('g/ml')}")
    print(f"to stuff = {result.to('stuff')}")


def main():
    u.define('stuff = (g/l) * 10')

    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    more_last_minute_sub = [["g/100mL", "stuff"]]  # [bad text/regex, new text]
    config.last_minute_sub += more_last_minute_sub  # Here we are adding to the existing list of units

    text = ("12.5g / 100mL")
```

Is there a better way to do this ? Or should I stick to this workaround ? Is there a better library to use ?

Answer (score 3):

Isn't plain old [`UnitRegistry.parse_string()`](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/0.20.1/getting/tutorial.html#string-parsing) enough?

```
>>> pattern = '{gram}g/{milliliter}ml'
>>> input_str = '12.5g/100ml'
>>> mass, vol = ureg.parse_pattern(input_str, pattern)
>>> print((mass / vol).to('g / l'))
125.00000000000001 gram / liter
```

Comment: Great solution. What should I do if I'm searching for multiple patterns ? Should I create a list to loop and apply `ureg.parse_pattern()` to all of them to see if there is a match ?

Comment: @cuzureau, I have another idea, using _unit-parse_, but I won't be at my machine for a couple of days.  I'll post another answer, if nobody has the same idea before that.

Comment: Can you at least give me some details about your solution ^^ ? I don't have to necessarily use unit-parse. I want to use the most efficient and straightforward way to do it.

Comment: @cuzureau, try using `more_last_minute_sub` to add parentheses like '12.5 g/ (100ml)'.  It should be easy to do with regexes, and that string seems to be parsed correctly by _unit-parse_

Comment: I could not make it work. BUT you gave me this idea : I used `more_last_minute_sub` not to add parentheses but to change `g/100mL` to `g/dL` which is equivalent ! I forgot my science for a moment ^^. This way the parser understand it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`config.pre_proc_sub`](https://github.com/dylanwal/unit_parse#pre-processing-substitutions) to turn `"12.5g / 100mL"` (before being processed) to something like `"12.5g / (100mL)"`, which is parsed correctly, and not as `"(12.5g / 100) * mL"`

```
>>> more_pre_processing = [(r'/([0-9.]+\s*\S+)', r'/(\1)')]
>>> unit_parse.config.pre_proc_sub += more_pre_processing
>>> input_str = '12.5g/100ml'
>>> print(unit_parse.parser(input_str).to('g / l'))
125.00000000000001 g / l
```